# What is the point of the payload in reset password API with JWT

Tags: api, jwt

I am trying to write an API that allows the user to reset their password via their email.

I have been following https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/11/safe-password-resets-with-json-web-tokens/, but I am a bit confused. They are sending the email and user_id in the payload as JSON, but they never actually need this information. The only time they use the payload data is when they could easily retrieve the same data from another source.

So what is the point in sending it?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that the setup as described would not depend on the contents of the payload as the successful decryption already implies correct details. In this implementation then there is no point besides a sanity check (for example make sure the decoded user id is the same as the requested renewal id).

However, the article has glossed over the fact that in practice most JWTs contain and verify against the standard aud(audience), iss(issuer), sub(subject) and exp(expiry) claims in the payload. The expiry claim in particular is something I feel the article has missed (they've only considered the one-use problem), since you don't want unused reset tokens to be valid indefinitely while being stored on the relatively insecure location of a email server.

So to answer your question simply, the point of the payload in password reset is to put information to allow you to double check for valid JWT/ valid request before performing the reset.

Slightly off topic: I have some reservations regarding the article's suggestion of generating the JWT secret based on a user's password hash (may be weak due to poor password) and create date (may be public for something like a profile showing how long you've been a member etc.). The quoted benefit of ensuring one-use can be done without creating secrets from user details and the point of not leaking the secret if an attacker has the user password from other sites is not much help since they can login directly with that password.

Comment: I already changed the payload to simply include the expiry date of the token. What exactly are aud/iss/sub and how would I implement them?

Comment: How would you go about generating a JWT if not from the hash and create date? The create date will not be public.

Comment: I should note I'm currently hashing the result of `password_hash + str(date)` with SHA3_256.

Comment: Where `password_hash` is their hashed and salted password and `date` is a date like `2020-01-06 14:22:11.431023`.

Comment: @FJ It is not necessary to have a different secret per token, you can use a single secret key per application to generate them. The article only does this to auto revoke tokens when password is changed. You could for example store a list of valid reset tokens in db and delete the entry when used instead.

Comment: @FJ The other claims are defined by the JWT specs and are added no differently from other parts of the payload. If you have time I suggest reading through how to use JWT in authentication in general before using them in reset password. It will give you a better handle on how the whole process works

Comment: A single secret key per application is surely much less secure than my approach. Using a database is much more resource intensive. I am confident that my approach is secure and you haven't presented any reasons to the contrary. It seems like I don't need to include any of the things you mentioned into my payload - why would I?

Comment: @FJ Having more secrets doesn't make the process more secure especially since you're basing it on user defined variables. You'll need to access the DB to set the new password anyway so there is no new overhead. You're free to disagree but I only argue thus to help you with your question. Best wishes.